# Efficent use of an index for a self join with a group by

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I'm trying to speed up the following

```
create table tab2 parallel 24 nologging compress for query high as
select /*+ parallel(24) index(a ix_1) index(b ix_2)*/ 
       a.usr
       ,a.dtnum
       ,a.company
       ,count(distinct b.usr) as num
       ,count(distinct case when b.checked_1 = 1 then b.usr end) as num_che_1
       ,count(distinct case when b.checked_2 = 1 then b.usr end) as num_che_2
from tab a
join tab b on a.company = b.company
              and b.dtnum between a.dtnum-1 and a.dtnum-0.0000000001                 
group by a.usr, a.dtnum, a.company;
```

by using indexes

```
create index ix_1 on tab(usr, dtnum, company);
create index ix_2 on tab(usr, company, dtnum, checked_1, checked_2);
```

but the execution plan tells me that it's going to be an index full scan for both indexes, and the calculations are very long (1 day is not enough).

About the data. Table tab has over 3 mln records. None of the single columns are unique. The unique values here are pairs of (usr, dtnum), where dtnum is a date with time written as a number in the format yyyy,mmddhh24miss.    Columns checked_1, checked_2 have values from set (null, 0, 1, 2). Company holds an id for a company.
Each pair can only have one value checked_1, checked_2 and company as it is unique. Each user can be in multple pairs with different dtnum.

**Edit**

**@Roberto Hernandez**: I've attached the picture with the execution plan. As for parallel 24, in our company we are told to create tables with options 'parallel [num] nologging compress for query high'. I'm using 24 but I'm no expert in this field.

[image]

**@Sayan Malakshinov**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40b6b/2 Here I've simplified by giving data with checked_1 = checked_2, but in real life this may not be true.

**@scaisEdge**:
For

```
create index my_id1 on tab (company, dtnum);
create index my_id2 on tab (company, dtnum, usr);
```

I get
[image]
[image]

Comment: Provide your sample data please

Comment: can you provide explain plan of the original query

Comment: why parallel 24 ? where are you getting that number ? why not let Oracle decides which degree is the best one ?

Answer (score 0):

For table `tab` Your join condition is based on columns

```
company, datun
```

so you index should be primarly based on these columns

```
create index my_id1 on tab (company, datum);
```

The indexes  you are using are useless because don't contain in left most position columsn use ij join /where condition

Eventually you can add user right most potition for avoid the needs of table access  and let the db engine retrive alla the inf inside the index values

```
 create index my_id1 on tab (company, datum, user, checked_1, checked_2);
```

Comment: See the execution plans in the edit of my question. These indexes don't look good.

Comment: @stolikp  then you don't have much chance to improve performance ... ..anyway answer updated  adding redundance alos cof checked_1 _2

Comment: OK. The updated answer is no different from what I did. The execution plan is the same as in the first picture.

Comment: How many unique values in Company and datum ? Have you tried using bitmap indxes rather than B-Tree indexes

Comment: Distinct companies: 16 847, distinct dtnums: 2 775 994, all rows: 3 366 074.
Should I try a bitmap index with these? If yes, on which columns?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes (bitmap or otherwise) are not that useful for this execution. If you look at the execution plan, the optimizer thinks the group-by is going to reduce the output to 1 row. This results in serialization (PX SELECTOR) So I would question the quality of your statistics. What you may need is to create a column group on the three group-by columns, to improve the cardinality estimate of the group by.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Are you saying that I should use a grouping set on the three columns?  That is, group by grouping sets((a.usr, a.dtnum, a.company))? That didn't change the fact that PX SELECTOR is in the execution plan and the resulting cardinality is predicted as 1. Moreover, I tried 'ANALYZE TABLE tab COMPUTE STATISTICS', but no changes to the execution plan after the new analysis.

Comment: 1. Look at the explain plan - the estimated cardinality of the group-by is 1. That is suspicious to me - but you know your data; is that correct? If not, then 2. I suggest creating a column group (nothing to do with grouping sets). See the doc for DBMS_STATS.CREATE_EXTENDED_STATS.  3. Lastly, the ANALYZE command has been deprecated for about a decade for gathering stats. You should use DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS. And you should do this, after creating the column group in 2 above, making sure to collect a histogram on the column group.